# Total scrollable height of QListView

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlistview

Need to find the total height of a `QListView`, not its viewport's height.

This is simple with a `QScrollArea` which is derived from the same base class `QAbstractScrollArea` as QListView:

```
QScrollArea *sa;
sa->widget()->height();   // total height
sa->viewport()->height(); // viewport height
```

But I could not find an equivalent function for `QListView`. In case such a convenience function is lacking, what would be the best way to calculate the total height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a good way, but it's the only working way I know. Use `view->visualRect(index).bottom()`, where `index` is the last item's index. But it can be inaccurate. For example, if you want to set the view's height based on this value, you'd better add several pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Btw, I was wondering if we can obtain the length of the handle of its vertical scrollbar and infer its total height from that? I understand this will not be accurate either but a generic solution based on QAbstractScrollArea would be great

Comment: Good idea. You can do it using `verticalScrollBar()->maximum() - verticalScrollBar()->minimum()`. Tell me if it works. But be aware that scrollbars are not always visible by default.